# find average of unique data in list in python

Tags: python, filter, average

Data columns are as follows: City, First Name, Last Name, Gender, Age, Weight. The client can be entered more than once and recorded with a different weight.

I uniquely identified the clients and genders by doing the following:

Now I want to find the average age for the unique clients. Not sure how to do so?
Also, I want to report how many clients have been weighed more than once. The client would be listed as many times as their weight was recorded. Here is my class

```
class clients:
    def __init__(self, city, name, gender, age, weight):
        self.City = city
        self.Name = name
        self.Gender = gender
        self.Age = age
        self.Weight = weight
```

Comment: 1. Can you please specify the set of attributes that should be used to decide on the "uniqueness" of the client, since you wrote that the same client may be listed many times?
2. Is it possible that the same client will have historical data (with different ages)?
3. How are clients data stored? Is it a list, or ....

Comment: is the client name unique? Your class is badly named; this is a a weight record, not "clients"

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to the topic:

1. some corrections to the class declaration, so it would account for uniqueness

```python
class Clients:
    def __init__(self, city, first_name, last_name, gender, age, weight, uuid):
        self.City = city
        self.FirstName = first_name
        self.LastName = last_name
        self.Gender = gender
        self.Age = age
        self.Weight = weight
        self.UUID = uuid
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.City == other.City and \
            self.FirstName == other.FirstName and \
            self.LastName == other.LastName and \
            self.Gender == other.Gender and \
            self.Age == other.Age and \
            self.Weight == other.Weight and \
            self.UUID == other.UUID:
            return True
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.City, self.FirstName, self.LastName, self.Gender, self.Age, self.Weight, self.UUID))
```

2. assuming that you have a simple list of different entries like:

```python
import uuid

list_of_measurements = []
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamburg", "Foo", "Bar", "Apache", 31, 80, uuid.uuid4()))
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamburg", "Foo", "Bar", "Apache", 31, 82, list_of_measurements[0].UUID))  # new weight measurement
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamburg", "Foo", "Bar", "Apache", 32, 83, list_of_measurements[0].UUID))  # new weight measurement, age changed
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamville", "Foo", "Bar", "Apache", 33, 83, list_of_measurements[0].UUID))  # new weight measurement, client moved
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamville", "Foo", "Bar", "Apache", 33, 83, list_of_measurements[0].UUID))  # duplicate measurement
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamville", "Foo", "Bar", "Hind", 33, 83, list_of_measurements[0].UUID))  # client underwent gender change
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamville", "Foo", "ZanziBar", "Hind", 33, 83, list_of_measurements[0].UUID))  # client got married and changed their last name
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamville", "Foo Too", "Bar None", "Hind", 23, 63, uuid.uuid4()))  # second unique client
list_of_measurements.append(Clients("Spamville", "Foo Three", "Bar Some", "Apache", 18, 60, uuid.uuid4()))  # third unique client
```

Please note how everything except of UUID may actually change for each customer.

3. finding amount of unique customers - can be obtained by using a set:

```python
set_of_clients = set([c.UUID for c in list_of_measurements]) # will only contain unique UUIDs
```

4. reporting on clients who have more than one weight measurement - can be done using a dict and sum:

```python
measurements_dict = {uid: sum(1 for c in list_of_measurements if c.UUID == uid) for uid in set_of_clients}
list_of_customers_with_more_than_one_measurement = [uid for uid, m in measurements_dict.items() if m > 1]
print(list_of_customers_with_more_than_one_measurement)
```

5. removing potentially duplicate measurments - can be done by casting to list and to set, which requires previously defined **eq** and **hash** properties of the class

```python
list_of_deduplicated_measurements = list(set(list_of_measurements))
```

6. average age, presuming that you want to average only on the last recorded age of the customer

```python
from statistics import mean

ages_dict = {uid: max(c.Age for c in list_of_measurements if c.UUID == uid) for uid in set_of_clients}
average_age = mean(ages_dict.values())
```